# Error monitoring in Phoenix apps

Tags: monitoring, elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I monitor errors in my Phoenix application similar to https://airbrake.io/ for Ruby on Rails apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no Airbrake Hex package yet, but Jared Norman has put together a Plug for BugSnag integration. You could give the BugSnag service a try, or use his code as a base to put together an Airbrake package.

https://github.com/jarednorman/plugsnag

Answer (score 1):

I've written the similar plug to work with Airbrake:
https://github.com/romul/airbrake_plug

Feel free to use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link is a complete answer to the question. There is nothing to add except copy-pasting all README and Wiki page from repository. But it's no sense, b/c it could be changed much more probable than the link.